# dotCover Nunit over command line

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, ncover, dotcover

I'm trying to run dotCover over command line. It's working fine with VisualStudio2010 but its not working over command line.
I get the error: "Either assembly contains no tests or proper test driver has not been found."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMIU6.png)

My config.xml looks like this (hold very simple)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WQhY.png)

I made this ".dll" with VisualStudio2010 and I tested it also

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. For me the "test.dll" should contain the suitable tests, so I don't understand what I have to do diffrent to make it work.

Please help! Or ask for more information... thank you!